# Why is my model scope not working and returning an empty array?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Why do I get an empty collection result using the scope? This is my current controller:

```php
class PunxController extends Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $scholars = Scholar::age()->get();

        return $scholars;
    }
}
```

and on my model `Scholar`:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Scholar extends Model {

    protected $primaryKey = 'scholar_id';
    protected $fillable = ['ngo_id','scholar_lname','scholar_fname','scholar_image','scholar_nickname','scholar_cityAddress','scholar_permaAddress','scholar_birthday','scholar_placebirth','scholar_age','scholar_gender','scholar_email','scholar_contact'];

    public static function scopeAge($query)
    {
        return $query->where('scholar_age', '>=', 5);
    }
}
```

and the result is:

[image]

but when I try on **PHPMYADMIN**:

[image]

**Update1**

result of `DB::getQueryLog()`:

[image]

Comment: Try running `\DB::enableQueryLog()` before you run the query and then use `dd(\DB::getQueryLog())` after to see what was actually run. Then post the result here please!

Comment: @Jonathon here it is, check the update

Comment: Thanks. That query looks right. Which tells me that it's possible not looking at the right database. Are you running your webserver using a VM like vagrant?

Comment: @Jonathon I'm just running WAMP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `static` keyword from your method. Scopes shouldn't be static.

```php
public function scopeAge($query)
{
    return $query->where('scholar_age', '>=', 5);
}
```

I'm guessing you would like to provide `5` as a parameter to the scope rather than hard-coding it. In which case you can do:

```php
public function scopeAge($query, $age)
{
    return $query->where('scholar_age', '>=', $age);
}
```

And call it like

```php
Scholar::age(5)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
public function scopeAge($query)
{
    return $query->where('scholar_age', '>=', 5);
}
```